# Trying to load penlight lua modules from C

Tags: c++, c, lua

I am beginning to put my hands in lua and have had a quite frustrating experience so far.
I need to load portions of penlight, in order to load "mine.lua" that requires pl.import_into. I need to do this from C/C++.

I am using lua 5.1; using 5.2 is not an option atm so I don't have luaL_requiref

Roughly my code looks like this:

```
void luaLoad(lua_State* L, const char* f) {
  if (luaL_dofile(L, f) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)) {
    const char* err = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, -1);
    throw std::runtime_error("Lua load error");
  }
}
int main(void) {
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);
  luaLoad(L, "~/Penlight-1.3.1/lua/pl/compat.lua");
  luaLoad(L, "~/Penlight-1.3.1/lua/pl/utils.lua");
  luaLoad(L, "~/Penlight-1.3.1/lua/pl/import_into.lua");
  luaLoad(L, "mine.lua");
  ...
}
```

I started trying to load import_into.lua, which required utils.lua and transitively compat.lua.

In my luaLoad method, if I drop the lua_pcall, utils.lua "does not see" compat.lua:

```
utils.lua : module 'pl.compat' not found`
```

With the lua_pcall however I get an

```
attempt to call a table value` error.
```

Is trying to load penlight from C fundamentally wrong ?

Comment: What OS are you using? Does it expand tildes? Cool.

Comment: In case my comment wasn't clear: are you aware of the tilde? It's the shell who handles it, not the kernel. You can't normally use it like that. Anyway, why not have your project have a "bootstrap.lua" file and do everything there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: The `lua_pcall` is superfluous. `luaL_dofile` already does a `lua_pcall`. The `lua_pop` call is also wrong.
Second: Any reason why you don't just modify `package.path`, so that Lua's `require` function can find the necessary modules?

If you can't or don't want to do that, there are two approaches:

In addition to running the module code you also need to store its result in the `package.loaded` table using the module name as the key. This way the `require` function called in the penlight code can find those modules later.

```
void luaLoad(lua_State* L, char const* m, const char* f) {
  int top = lua_gettop(L);
  if (luaL_dofile(L, f)) {
    const char* err = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 1); /* the 2nd parameter is a number not a stack index! */
    throw std::runtime_error("Lua load error");
  } else {
    lua_settop(L, top+1); /* discard anything but first return value */
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "_LOADED"); /* get `package.loaded` */
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2); /* `lua_setfield` needs the return value at stack top */
    lua_setfield(L, -2, m); /* store return value as `package.loaded[m]` */
    lus_settop(L, top); /* restore Lua stack */
  }
}
```

Advantages are that you can use the same function to run your `mine.lua`. The downside is that you have to load the modules in the correct order, and if one of the modules uses the `module` function, the code gets a little more complicated (basically you are reimplementing parts of Lua's `require` function).

The second approach is to load *but not run* the modules and put the loaded code (which is a Lua function) in the `package.preload` table using the module name as the key. The `require` function can later pick them up and run them from there.

```
void luaPreload(lua_State* L, char const* m, char const* f) {
  if (luaL_loadfile(L, f)) {
    char const* err = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    throw std:runtime_error("Lua load error");
  } else {
    lua_getglobal(L, "package"); /* there is no shorthand for `package.preload` */
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -3); /* `lua_setfield` needs the function at stack top */
    lua_setfield(L, -2, m); /* store chunk as `package.preload[m]` */
    lua_pop(L, 3); /* restore Lua stack */
  }
}
```

Advantages are that require will run the modules in the correct order automatically, and the `module` function doesn't need special handling. A disadvantage is that you need separate code to run `mine.lua`.

All those approaches assume that `mine.lua` uses Lua's `require` function to access the penlight modules.